# Strange route fulid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want to make a animation of water going down an pipe like string, but the water behaves really strangely. For detail, here is the screenshot and my settings.

[image]

The pipe is made by screw tool.

[image]

Do you guys meet situation like this? Any suggestions?

Edit: I tried to scale to make objects much smaller and set resolution to 100, but it do not work at all.

Comment: Can you add the blend file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are three problems:

- Normals the wrong direction
- Single-walled pipe
- Fluid is too low resolution

Solving the second problem will probably also solve the first problem, but it's worth mentioning both.

The simulation uses the normals to determine where the "surface" is, and normals are only on one side of a polygon. If your normals are on the outside of the pipe, then the simulation will be confused.

This can be solved by "solidifying" your pipe. Use a Solidify modifier, and make sure that it's **above** the fluid sim modifier, in the stack (or you can just apply the solidify modifier).  This will help the simulation figure out what's the inside of the pipe.

Lastly, if the simulation doesn't have enough resolution, then the fluid will be "too big" for the pipe. If the resolution is too low, then it won't have enough precision to accurately determine if the fluid is inside the pipe or outside the pipe. So, increase your resolution of your fluid domain.

[image]

There's also a decent demonstration of how different resolutions behave.

https://vimeo.com/373280749

Comment: I wanted to add a comment to Matt's post to say this instead but don't have enough reputation so I'm trying this. Thanks Matt for linking my video comparing fluid sim resolutions. The video has been moved here: https://vimeo.com/373280749 I wanted to do this so that the video wasn't lost to those searching in the future and finding this post via google. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There may be couple of things to check on.

You should apply the screw modifier as non applied modifier don't take effect in some simulations.

The inflow velocity dons't match the orientation of your obstacle,In your case it would be -0.5 in Y and -0.1 in X for instance.

Comment: The screw modify is not in stack, and I have tried the value you suggest, the water still grow out of the pipe.